# Google Maps SDK for iOS: Relocating the Google logo

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-mobile, google-maps-sdk-ios

For the new sdk for iOS, is the Google logo relocatable, just like Mapkit pre-iOS 6? Also, is it allowed under terms of conditions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the terms of the Google Maps there are following sentences concerning the Google logo:

> 8.4 (b) Restrictions. In using Google Brand Features, you will not:
>
> ...
>
> (iii) have the Google logo as the largest logo in your Maps API
>   Implementation or on your website (except as displayed in the map
>   image itself);

and furtherer more there also is the sentence

> 9.4 Attribution.
>   (a) Content provided to you through the Service may contain the trade names, trademarks, service marks, logos, domain
>   names, and other distinctive brand features of Google, its partners,
>   or other third party rights holders of content indexed by Google. When
>   Google provides this attribution, you must display it as provided
>   through the Service or as described in the Maps APIs Documentation and
>   may not delete or in any manner alter these trade names, trademarks,
>   service marks, logos, domain names, and other distinctive brand
>   features.

So as I read this you are not allowed to modify the position or any attributes of the Google logo itself. But I didn't found any restriction which do not allow a layer or something above the Google logo.

But please note I am not a lawyer and in my purposes I don not see any reason why to modify the Google logo.

Best regards
Robert

Answer (score 11):

This is actually possible to some sort of degree by changing the visible portion of the map, aka `padding`:

```
let padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 100, right: 0)
mapView.padding = padding
```

This can be useful if you have a drawer like view on top of the map and you want the center to be moved accordingly when you change the camera (without moving the whole UIView which performs worse). Or just to move the logo to the right.

If you take a look at the documentation [map_padding][https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/map#map_padding]

> If you display a custom UI at the bottom of the map, add padding to the bottom of the map so that the logo and legal notices will always be visible.

Just as a heads up, when changing the `padding`, if you move the camera, you may want to add an inset to it to cancel that margin that you just used to move the logo (to cancel each other out):

```
mapView.camera(for: bounds, insets: insets)
```

Comment: just set equal inset from top and bottom (or left and right sides) and there will be no need for `mapView.camera(for: bounds, insets: insets)`